# htaccess - Wrong htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^expit\.online$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://expit.online:2018$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But don't work redirect from http to https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need an `[OR]` in your conditions?

Try changing your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```